# Setting SSRS Tablix Minimum Height

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to set the Tablix with a **Fixed height** or **Minimum Height**? Currently the height of the table is determined by the number of rows. Please help.

If we can then, how can i do? I didnt found any properties in BIDS to set the Property.

Or, If any Perfect alternatives? Please Let me know.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way of doing that but you can create empty rows outside the groups of the tablix and then hide them (using the Row Visibility property) if the data in your dataset contains a certain number of rows.